# How to get a specific word from html page using beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have to extract specific words from a HTML page and count the number of times the word has been repeated. How do I do this using beautiful soup in python? How do I pass the url in the soup and then count the words ?

This is my code till now. I have no idea what to do next.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(paragraph.string)
    print(str(paragraph.text))
```

Comment: What are these words that you're trying to extract?

Comment: It's too early to ask this question. Keep learning.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm trying to extract words Internet and Computer. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Well, it isn't hard. Try googling a bit more. Hint: Use soup.find_all with a `text` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the text in the page using

```
soup.get_text()
```

After setting that to a variable you could then use the .count() method to find the amount that a certain string appears in the HTML page. e.g.

```
text = soup.get_text()
print (text.count('word'))
```

To make sure you aren't getting words inside words you could split everything with a space and then look for them in each index of the list. For example 'house' is inside 'houses' would be fixed by this.